# AsyncTask keeps crashing demo app running on Android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I'm currently learning Android app development by working through a book and I'm currently struggling with something that seems to be fairly simple on the face of it. The interface consists of a button and a text view. The idea of the exercise is to demonstrate how using a separate thread is useful when performing time consuming tasks.

I've tried debugging and the `values` array of the `onProgressUpdate` method does contain the value passed into it and the crash seems to always happen when trying to set the text for `myTextView`. I'd be grateful for any help.

Code:

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.asyncdemo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView myTextView;
    private String tag = "Test";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void buttonClick(View view) {
        AsyncTask task = new MyTask().execute();
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            Log.i(tag,"publish: " + Integer.toString(values[0]));
            myTextView.setText("Counter = " + values[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            myTextView.setText(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            int i = 0;
            while (i <= 20) {
                Log.i(tag,"before publish: " + Integer.toString(i));
                publishProgress(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    i++;
                } catch(Exception e) {

                }
            }

            return "Button Pressed";
        }
    }
}
```

The Logcat output (created by the Log.i items added by me for troubleshooting) is usually the below but if the warning message that advises the app keeps crashing pops up the "before publish" item keeps populating with i incrementing each time until I close the warning message:

```
2020-12-13 23:17:04.499 31729-31772/com.ebookfrenzy.asyncdemo I/Test: before publish: 0
2020-12-13 23:17:04.503 31729-31729/com.ebookfrenzy.asyncdemo I/Test: publish: 0
```

The error section of the Logcat:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2020-12-13 23:19:47.635 353-353/com.ebookfrenzy.asyncdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ebookfrenzy.asyncdemo, PID: 353
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.ebookfrenzy.asyncdemo.MainActivity$MyTask.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:34)
        at com.ebookfrenzy.asyncdemo.MainActivity$MyTask.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:25)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:715)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2020-12-13 23:19:47.639 353-353/com.ebookfrenzy.asyncdemo I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 353 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `myTextView` is `null`, because you never assign a value to the field. Note that `AsyncTask` is deprecated, and it has been considered a sub-par solution for a few years now. You might want to look for a newer book.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I missed that line from the sample code in the book. The book Android Studio 4.0 Development Essentials which was published in June 2020 but maybe this is a blind spot. Or perhaps it mentions later in the chapter that the class is outdated. What should be used instead?

Comment: Interesting. That book covers view binding in Chapter 18, if I am reading the table of contents correctly, so I am surprised that this example relies on `findViewById()`, since that book does not cover `AsyncTask` until Chapter 65. I would recommend coroutines instead of `AsyncTask` (Chapter 66), but you are not programming in Kotlin, even though that book seems to cover it. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: The view binding was added after initial publication so the author advises the other examples haven't been updated but recommends trying it out. I just finished the AsyncTask chapter before logging off so I don't know what comes next but there are separate books available for java and kotlin so maybe you were looking at the contents for the kotlin version?

Comment: "maybe you were looking at the contents for the kotlin version?" -- it had a whole bunch of Kotlin chapters, so presumably that is the case. I had not noticed that they had different editions per language. And I thought *I* had a sometimes-confusing book lineup... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `myTextView` must be null.

Try this.

```
if (myTextView != null){
  myTextView.setText("Counter = " + values[0]);
}
```

And you should initialize `myTextView` at `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextviewid); // put 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the issue was that I hadn't initialised the ```myTextView``` variable.